# How can I uncheck a checkbox in GTK, when I press a button?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

How can I uncheck a check box in GTK when i press a button.Say am having an open and close button before opening I will tick the check box but when I presses the close button it must automatically uncheck the check box. How can I acquire that in gtk programming? I tried using check box properties and widget properties, but none of them worked. I tried using gtk set sensitive but when using that the check box gets disabled but still the tick remains

```
gtk_widget_set_sensitive(normal,FALSE);
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't forget: "I" is always uppercase in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `xxx_set_active()`.

get_active() and set_active() let you see the current state, and change it to "checked" and "unchecked".

Comment: Can you explain which widget have these properties

Comment: It's really not hard to look that up in the reference: start from the widget you are using and keep going up in object hierarchy until you find what you need... In this case look at GtkCheckButton, see that it is derived from GtkToggleButton and find `gtk_toggle_button_set_active()`